# можно ли менять ширину border-bottom не трогая сам блок

Tags: html, css, border

[image: то как должен выглидеть]

[image: то как выглидит у меня]

один из моих недопопыток

```
.watches__time{
    grid-column-start: 1;
    grid-column-end: 4;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: auto;
    margin-bottom: auto;
    font-family: Playfair Display;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 36px;
    line-height: 48px;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;

/* white */

    color: #FFFFFF;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;

}

.watches__time::before{
    content: "";
    width: 120px;
}
```

был бы рад узнать все ваши идеи, попробую все, может что-то и на правильную мысль сталкнет

Comment: box-sizing: border-box;

Answer (score 0):

можно реализовать через псевдоэлемент, таким образом можете управлять и размером и положением линии. Вот пример:

```css
.watches__time {
  position: relative;

  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: 4;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: auto;
  margin-bottom: auto;
  font-family: Playfair Display;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 36px;
  line-height: 48px;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.watches__time::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 50%;
  background-color: red;
  bottom: -20px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0);
  height: 2px;
  width: 120px;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="watches__time">Example code</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно так попробовать:

```css
*, *::before, *::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

:root {
  --fontSize: 16px;
  --transitionTimingFunction: ease;
  --transitionDuration: 0.3s;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: var(--fontSize);
}

.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  --fontSize: 30px;
  --width: 0.8;
  font-size: var(--fontSize);
  cursor: pointer;
  user-select: none;
  padding: calc(var(--fontSize) / 4.8) calc(var(--fontSize) / 2.4);
}

.btn::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  width: calc(100% * var(--width));
  height: calc( var(--fontSize) / 10 );
  background-color: orange;
  
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0);
  transition-property: transform;
  transition-timing-function: var(--transitionTimingFunction);
  transition-duration: var(--transitionDuration);
}

.btn.btn-one:hover::after {
  transform: translate(-50%, 0) scaleX(0);
}

.btn.btn-two:hover::after {
  transform: translate(-50%, 0) scaleY(5);
}
```

```html
<div class="btn btn-one">Привет</div>
<div class="btn btn-two">Пока</div>
```